# Batch script does not run in temporary folder after decompressing SFX WinRAR file

Tags: batch-file, winrar, sfx, temporary-directory

I have a program with a separate setup for 32 and 64 bits. My goal is to create a single executable that can run the appropriate setup. So I created a folder and placed the two setups inside, then wrote the following script:

```
@echo off

if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 goto :x64
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%==AMD64 goto :x64

:x86
    "%cd%"\setup.exe
    exit

:x64
    "%cd%"\setup-x64.exe
    exit
```

Afterwards, I created the SFX file with this folder in WinRAR, pointing to the BAT file. But when I run it, a command line window pops up and shuts down instantly and nothing happens. I go to the temporary folder and double click the BAT file and the setup starts. The same happens in the original folder. What is happening and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `setlocal` then `pushd "%~dp0"` just below `@echo off` and see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: `"%~dp0setup.exe"` instead of `"%cd%"\setup.exe` and `"%~dp0setup-x64.exe"` instead of `"%cd%"\setup-x64.exe`?

Comment: @rojo and @JosefZ, both your solutions work! I discovered that the `%~dp0` means directing to the script location. I prefer to use the `pushd "%~dp0"` option, seems more elegant. However, do I really need `setlocal`? I didn't understand what it might be used for, from what I searched.

Comment: The `%~dp0` trick should fix the problem, but for debugging similar issues in the future, remove or comment-out the `@echo off` and put `pause` before all exit points: the command window should stay open you would be able to see the commands that were run (in this case showing the `%cd%` wasn't what you thought it was).

Comment: @Alegom You probably don't _need_ `selocal` in this case, since the thing that called the batch file _probably_ won't care that it changed the current directory. However, it's probably "good practice" in general so that calling a batch file doesn't leave you in a different directory (unless the purpose of the batch file is to change the directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%cd%` reffers to the directory of the call of the batch-file.

For example a batch-file is in `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Folder\bat.bat`:

```
echo %cd%
pause
```

and you start it for example from the command-line like this:

> `C:\>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Folder\bat.bat`

it should echo `C:\` as that is where you called it from.

Two ways from the comments to solve the problem:

Push the directory of the batch-file using `pushd "%~dp0"` -> will result in a change of the variable value of `%cd%`

or

do not use `"%cd%"` but `"%~dp0"`

Both ways use the fact that the zeroth argument of a batch-file is its path.

You can prevent the command-line window from closing if you are debugging the file from the command-prompt itself if possible. With that you should have seen an error that state something like `...\setup.exe not found`. After that nothing had to be done from the batch-file so it closed.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation! I'm marking this as the answer, but all four of you contributed, for which I'm thankful.

Comment: I'm thankful someone else went to the trouble of explaining.  +1 from me.  :)

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful! @rojo it helps me learning as well so I am happy to help :)